To add column in leave entitlement page of OrangeHrm latest version
I'm currently working with the latest version of OrangeHRM, and I'm facing a customization challenge within the Leave Entitlement page. The Leave Entitlement page is a crucial component of our HR management system, providing essential information about employees' leave allocations and balances. However, we've identified a need to enhance this page by adding a custom column to display additional information related to leave entitlements.
I attempted to customize the Leave Entitlement page in OrangeHRM but not working. I'm seeking guidance on how to proceed with this customization and what steps to take to successfully add a custom column to the page. My expectation is to receive advice, recommendations, and best practices for implementing this customization effectively within OrangeHRM's framework.
